# How to display airprint popup in ios7 ipad with livecode external rrhardcoy?

Tags: ios, ipad, livecode, airprint

I need a airprint button in my livecode project.(developed for ipad ios 7).
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested the rreHardCopy external with the sample code that is supplied with the SDK and the print pop up shows as expected-

```
 on mouseUp
  local tPDFFile
  put specialFolderPath("Documents") & slash & "test.pdf" into tPDFFile
  delete file tPDFFile
  open printing to pdf tPDFFile
  print this card
  close printing
  rreHardcopyPrintPDF tPDFFile, "Test PDF Print"
  answer "PrintPDF returned" && the result
end mouseUp
```

This was tested on both the simulator and physical device.

A link to a build of the external I made can be found here-

http://techsupport.on-rev.com/sostacks/rrehardcopy%20DEVICE.zip

http://techsupport.on-rev.com/sostacks/rrehardcopy%20SIMULATOR.zip

[image: picture showing print pop up]

Comment: thankyou Neil Roger, but i got building errors, i have posted with screen shots, plz look there, and help me.  http://forums.runrev.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=19438&p=98291#p98291

Comment: guys plz do this with livecode stable 6.5.2 version.

Comment: thats great to hear Raja. For others reading this post, please make sure you are using the latest revision of LiveCode (currently 6.5.2) as issues that are present in previous revisions could cause issues when creating apps that contain externals.

Comment: Dear Neil Roger,
can u do build the rremicrophone too, and send me the lcext please.
I think my x code, has a problem, its not running properly.
And i have already did rremicrophone for armv7 , its working for me too, but in case of livecode versions greater than 6.1 its not working. please help me.

Comment: it looks like thierry has posted a link to these externals on the forums http://forums.runrev.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=19438&p=98291#p98291. Please keep us posted on how you get on

Comment: Dear All, 

in ipad, if we exit a application by pressing HOME button, and return to the same application , the app will just resume from where it is stopped actully.

But in case of LIvecode, the complete app is loading again. Is there any way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if you have compiled the external and included it into your project:

```
on mouseUp
  rreHardcopyPrintPDF
end mouseUp
```

If you have problems with compiling or including the external, please make clear what you have done so far exactly.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I have build the rreHardCopy with xcode 4.6, and add that .lcext files to my livecode project, iam able to see the airprint option is available by sending command "rreHardcopyIsAvailable" , iam getting true as result, but for printing data iam unable to get airprint popup on ipad device , iam using "rreHardcopyPrintPDF" command for printing , by the way i dont find rreHardCopy command as you mensioned in on mouseUp function in ur reply

Comment: @RajaRamesh In the LiveCode forum, it was suggested that the external didn't work with the current combination of XCode, LC SDK R14 and LC 6.x. From your response here, I understand that you are able to compile the external. I have changed my reply to include the correct command. Can you look in iPhone's console messages in XCode and see if the external reports anything back?